# Imprimir posiciones pares JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Crear función llamada posPares que reciba un arreglo y retorne un nuevo arreglo con los valores en las posiciones pares del arreglo que llega como argumento.

```
function posPares(arreglo){
  const arrFiltrado = arreglo.filter(num => num % 2 == 0)
  return arrFiltrado
}

// Resultados esperados
console.log(posPares(["a", "b", "c"])) // ["a", "c"]
console.log(posPares([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])) // [0, 2, 4]
console.log(posPares([])) // []
```

El segundo y tercer resultado me da de acuerdo a lo esperado, pero debo es dar los resultados es de acuerdo a la posición, y no de acuerdo al valor de dicha posición-

Answer (score 1):

La función callback que recibe `filter()` también puede recibir como parámetro el índice del elemento actual y se puede usar ese índice para hacer el filtrado:

```js
function posPares(arreglo){
  const arrFiltrado = arreglo.filter((num, index) => index % 2 == 0)
  return arrFiltrado
}

// Resultados esperados
console.log(posPares(["a", "b", "c"])) // ["a", "c"]
console.log(posPares([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])) // [0, 2, 4]
console.log(posPares([])) // []
```

Nota: según el enunciado se requieren las posiciones pares pero los resultados esperados son las posiciones impares.

Comment: Gracias por la explicaciòn @Lobos

Answer (score 1):

Ok, recuerda que filter tambien tiene otros parametros aparte del `valor actual`, el segundo parametro es el index, por to tanto puedes representarlo de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
function posPares(arreglo){
  return arreglo.filter((value, index) => {
    if(index % 2 == 0) return value
  })
}
```

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Gracias por la indicación @DavEksanto